# How to manipulate tkinter canvas objects with multiple tags

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I have many objects in my canvas. They all share one tag in common, plus they all have a unique tag.

```
tag = {"tt" + str(n) + str(m), "tray"}
```

I collect these tags as per bellow

```
tags = create_tags.tray_pocket_tag[n][m]
```

This returns me {'tray', 'tt00'} and an object is created with that set of tags.

```
canvas.create_rectangle(x1, y1, x2, y2, outline="black", fill="red", tags=tags)
root.update()
```

Now I wanna be able to move all objects that share a tag "tray" at the same time to a different location.
I'm trying that like this

```
canvas.move("tray", 0, new_y_coord)
root.update()
```

I also wanna be able of changing the color of each object individually, hence the unique tag each object has.

I try this

```
tag = str(tags - "tray")
canvas.itemconfigure(tag, outline="black", fill="gray")
root.update()
```

But no success. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

From: `tag = {"tt" + str(n) + str(m), "tray"}`
To: `tag = ("tt" + str(n) + str(m), "tray")`